# Difference between autowired and using new keyword on autowired class in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, spring-annotations

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;
```

vs

```
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService = new EmployeeService();
```

Is using `new EmployeeService()` on autowired class different than just using `new EmployeeService()`?

Answer (score 6):

If a bean for `@Autowired` is injected it will override your created object. But if there is no bean created you have a fallback (in this case `new EmployeeService()`. That might be helpful for tests but it's kind of an anti-pattern because normally you just want one of both behaviours.

Comment: I consider this an anti-pattern also for tests. Even in tests you want to know exactly what injected where, statements like that obscure the code.